# Changing the textfield height in ember js using the attributes maxlength /size?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to increase the height of TextField element in Ember.js.

Even after binding the attributes during definition time, and using the **size** and/or **maxlength** attribute in the .hdb file, the size is not reflected when I view it.

Comment: You'll have to post some code to get much help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be possible! Maybe you should try the "rows" attribute and a textarea if you want to change the height?

Here's a JSBin showing changing the height of a textarea:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cukiki/edit?html,js,output

Changing the size of a text field with Ember is kind of funny but here it is working as well:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/hawavihoto/1/edit?html,js,output